# Porting an Eclipse RCP 3 App to e4, which packages to not re-use?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm in the process of porting an existing app built on Eclipse RCP 3 to RCP e4.  The goal is to create a pure e4 application.

I have not been able to find a coherent list of which RCP related packages should not be used in a pure e4 application.  Does anyone have a list of what not to use or know where to find such a list.  In my searches I've found bits and pieces of what not to use, but nothing that appeared to be complete.  Since I'm just starting to work on the port, I'd rather deal with removing RCP 3 only packages now rather than later.

Thanks for any help.

Paul